# Concatenar cadena en php

Tags: php

Deseo concatenar una variable de sesion que antes de su valor tenga un ' y al finalizar su valor tenga otra ' , como lo hago. Dejo codigo

```
$colorHeader = $_SESSION['_colorHeader'];
```

Por ejemplo:

La variable `$_SESSION['_colorHeader']` contiene `#FFFFFF` , y deseo que la variable `$colorHeader` sea igual a `'#FFFFFF'` , hay una comilla simple al inicio y otra al final.

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta, podrías colocar un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: La variable  $_SESSION['_colorHeader'] contiene #FFFFFF , y deseo que la variable $colorHeader sea igual a '#FFFFFF' , hay una comilla simple al inicio y otra al final

Comment: Si especificas el uso que le quieres dar quizá podríamos abordar una mejor respuesta. Si quieres tu variable rodeada de comillas simples, puedes obtenerla como en el ejemplo que tú mismo pones y al usarla: `$colorHeaderComillas=" ' ".$colorHeader." ' ";` (he puesto espacios sólo para que veas que hay una comilla simple que se concatena con la variable $colorHeader original), se los quitas y te irá de maravilla. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que buscas es concatenar las comillas simples con tu color, puedes tener algunas alternativas, revisa la documentación oficial de PHP con respecto al uso de [cadenas de caracteres](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/language.types.string.php).

Básicamente podrías usar el **Entrecomillado Doble** para realizar tu concatenación por ejemplo te pongo el siguiente ejemplo:

```
$ses['color'] = "#FFFFFF"; //entrada de color sin comillas
echo "'$ses[color]'"; //concatenación usando entrecomillado doble sin usar concatenación con punto(.)
```

En tu caso podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
$colorHeader = "'$_SESSION[_colorHeader]'";
```

Tambien puedes usar entrecomillado simple como se menciona en la respuesta de @Giovanni, otra alternativa es usar Heredoc, pero en este caso seria innecesario.

Answer (score 1):

A lo que entiendo $colorHeader la necesitas como una variables string, entonces lo más recomendable inicializala como `$colorHeader = '';` para después al asignarle el valor se la variable sesión automaticamente php recurra al tipo string.

En caso de que esto no sea lo que requieres y lo necesitar literal concatenar, realiza lo siguiente:

`$colorHeader = "'". $_SESSION['_colorHeader'] ."'";`

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 0):

La comilla simple no necesita barra de escape, por eso debería servirte

```
$colorHeader = "'". $_SESSION['_colorHeader'] ."'";
```